# Use xrandr to set the absolute position of the screen?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, display, xfce, xrandr

I am running XFCE on Fedora 15. I use xrandr to set the secondary display (HDMI-0) to be to the right of the primary (DVI-0), however it is always at the top-right. Is it possible to set the absolute position of the display (e.g. DVI-0 at 0,0 and HDMI-0 at 1920,56), or even set the display to be at the bottom-right?

I cannot modify the Xorg.conf, which would be the easy way, as that would mean generating an Xorg.conf file (there is none right now), and I do not know of any automated tool to do that (other than the fglrx driver).

The reason why I need this is because I want to extend the XFCE panel accross both monitors, but with there being a 56-pixel-wide dead zone at the bottom I cannot do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `--pos` switch should allow you to set the position of an individual output (ie monitor) within the overall virtual screen.

So you probably want to use `--pos 1920x56` or something on the output that drives the right hand monitor if I've understood the man page correctly.

Comment: I thought this didn't work with the "Awesome" window manager as it was cutting the top of the screen off, until I realised that you have to reload it (`Mod4+Ctrl+R`) before it will notice the change and put the windows back onto the visible area of the screen again.